# Rails Letting users create users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app using devise which works perfectly. I now want users to be able to provide the details of their previous customers, which I want to add to the user table. However, whenever it tries to create the new user, it fails because it's trying to create the user using the current session holders ID. Help!

**Controller**

```
class Suppliers::PreviousProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @new_user = User.new
end

def create
    @new_user = User.new(previous_projects_params)
    if @new_user.save
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Previous customer created'
    else
        render :new
    end
end

protected
    def previous_projects_params
        params.require(:user)
                    .permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email)
    end


end
```

**Routes**

```
get "suppliers/previous_projects/new" => 'suppliers/previous_projects#new'
post "suppliers/previous_projects/create" => 'suppliers/previous_projects#create'
```

**View**

```
<div id="customer_dashboard">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <%= render 'customers/menu' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <h1 class="page-header"><%= @title %></h1>
            <div class= "project_form">
                <%= form_for(@user, url:  suppliers_previous_projects_create_path(@user)) do |f| %>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <%= f.label :first_name, class: "required" %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, :required => 'required', class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <%= f.label :last_name, class: "required" %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :last_name, :required => 'required', class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <%= f.label "Mobile Number", class: "required" %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :phone, :required => 'required', class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <%= f.label :email, class: "required" %><br />
                    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => 'required', class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                    <div class="actions center space_big">
                        <%= f.submit "Save User", class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Log**

```
Started POST "/suppliers/previous_projects/create" for ::1 at 2017-01-27 11:04:08 +0200
Processing by Suppliers::PreviousProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u+/ydnO4lSBcJtuqOWNiqccRWosTydAZ3Kd81wwO+DbveFRUYw53JsI0x6bolaSQTapgSrw6njnboBDFfSNlIw==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Stev", "last_name"=>"Three", "phone"=>"23092309029309", "email"=>"steve3@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Save User"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "steve3@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendering suppliers/previous_projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered customers/_menu.html.erb (2.8ms)
Rendered suppliers/previous_projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 152ms (Views: 141.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

FYI - The user in this case should have had a new id. Instead it tried to give the user an id of 2, which was the id of the creating user. Greatly appreciate any help!

**Update**

This is a separate log entry if I use a completely random email address

```
Started POST "/suppliers/previous_projects/create" for ::1 at 2017-01-27 16:33:25 +0200
Processing by Suppliers::PreviousProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ezEpssYnOU1LProVW4I14qKjINcRfs2/EJdsHlrSGc/bzZUxny8NbbQJgEjEZljWxtyqhJ+mwYBkyGuiitjqeg==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Random First Name", "last_name"=>"Random Last Name", "phone"=>"093409239032902", "email"=>"ThisIsSomeRandomEmail@Email.com"}, "commit"=>"Save User"}
(0.9ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "thisissomerandomemail@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(12.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendering suppliers/previous_projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendered customers/_menu.html.erb (5.7ms)
Rendered suppliers/previous_projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 161ms (Views: 113.4ms | ActiveRecord: 14.2ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get through this by: 
1. changing the variable from @user to @new_user. 
2. Stipulating the create action and controller in the form using :url
3. Using Pry to set a break point and expect where everything was going wrong (binding.pry has literally changed my life!!)